# Asana: SSL in webhook creation

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, asana

I'm trying to create Asana webhook and the error I keep getting is: `asana.error.InvalidRequestError: Invalid Request: Could not complete activation handshake with target URL. Please ensure that the receiving server is accepting connections and supports SSL`

Service (gunicorn server) is running in Docker container mapped to port 8004, so webhook's url looks like `https://example.com:8004/path/to/webhook`. I have set up Let's Encrypt SSL for the whole domain.

The weird thing is that when I'm hitting webhook's url from Postman or Python everything works fine, therefore I'm not sure how can I reproduce Asana's handshake request.

On the other hand when I was testing webhooks locally with usage of `ngrok` everything worked good.

May Let's Encrypt certificate be somehow not acceptable by Asana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with Let's encrypt SSL.

Seems like Asana's handshake request is hitting SSL port (443) of the main domain despite the port specified in webhook's url.

The solution was to set up `nginx` proxy pass and turning off SSL in the gunicorn inside the docker container.

Something similar to:

```
  location /service-api {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8004;
  }
```

This way `nginx` handles SSL and passes already decrypted request to the service - and Asana is happy about the port